# JQL to get all JIRA issues logged in between specific sprint range

Tags: jira

I need to export all issues from Sprint 25-50. I couldn't find any filter in JIRA to do that.

Which JQL (jira query language)query I can write to do this?

Reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracore/blog/2015/07/search-jira-like-a-boss-with-jql

Answer (score 1):

You can use a similar JQL as mentioned below:

> project = YOUR_PROJECT_NAME and **cf[11901]** in("Sprint 25-50")

cf[11901] is a custom field name for **Sprint**, so the custom field name might be different to your JIRA instance. But you should be able to get the custom field name while typing `Sprint` in JQL query search box(note that your Admin should have enabled "JQL Auto-complete" feature ON).

Comment: It is working but not working as is. It is giving `There is not sprint found by the name Sprint 25-50`. We have Sprint alisas e.g. Sprint 25 is 263. Also this field `cf[10007]` is not accepting > or < operator so I can't fetch values between sprint range.

Comment: I believe you can't do range queries for Sprint. However, you can look out for "Sprint Report" or "Velocity Report" under "Reports" section to see if that helps: https://www.screencast.com/t/zSHhbxxY

Comment: I am using range of created date.